# Pandas left join leads to column full of 'NaT'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just trying to merge two data frames, where the first one (the left in the left join) is `data`:

```
    userid      date                                event
0   S3gFFFZtYF  2016-04-01 18:04:44.646000+00:00    goReview
1   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:07:43.461000+00:00    goReview
2   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:09:10.264000+00:00    requestReminder
3   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:09:34.526000+00:00    emailFeedback
4   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:10:07.161000+00:00    rejectFeedback
```

And the right table is `last_use_date`:

```
    last_date                           userid
0   2016-06-10 13:01:38.131000+00:00    00bt52e7Wg
1   2016-08-15 14:26:55.187000+00:00    01oqeMSMkN
2   2016-08-11 00:04:35.812000+00:00    0200dDUPWK
3   2016-08-15 15:13:13.567000+00:00    04mkzqD7e2
4   2016-08-14 16:19:04.582000+00:00    04Tj3htVwh
```

In `data` the same `userid` can appear more than once whereas in `last_use_date` each `userid` appears only once. The results of a left join are below. As you can see, I seem to lose all info from `last_use_date`.

```
data.join(last_use_date, on = 'userid', how = 'left', rsuffix = '_right').head()
```

results in:

```
    userid      date                                event           last_date   userid_right
0   S3gFFFZtYF  2016-04-01 18:04:44.646000+00:00    goReview            NaT     NaN
1   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:07:43.461000+00:00    goReview            NaT     NaN
2   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:09:10.264000+00:00    requestReminder     NaT     NaN
3   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:09:34.526000+00:00    emailFeedback        NaT    NaN
4   9iYv7VWA3l  2016-04-01 18:10:07.161000+00:00    rejectFeedback       NaT    NaN
```

**Why are all the times and userid values gone?**

Note, I have already verified that I do have an overlap in data:

```
set(last_use_date.userid) == set(data.userid)

True
```

Comment: You don't have any matching userids between the two tables.

Comment: @Barmar did you see the last part of my post?

Comment: Just look at the data. There's no `userid = S3gFFFZtYF` in `last_use_date`.

Comment: @Barmar above is only the head of each data frame.

Answer (score 1):

first things first. check your datatypes:

```
last_use_date.userid.dtype
data.userid.dtype
```

are they equal? Then, replace `join` for `merge` instead, as your key is not in the index but in the columns of your dataframe.

```
data.merge(last_use_date, on = 'userid', how = 'left', rsuffix = '_right')
```

That should solve your problem amigo.

Answer (score 1):

`.join` joins by *index* by default, not by common columns. Use `.merge` instead:

```
data.merge(last_use_date, left_on='userid', right_on='userid', sort=False, suffixes=('', '_right'))
```

Comment: You kept editing your answer...you did not have the correct solution initially.

Comment: if it joins by index, shouldn't it join the two rows with `index = 0` from the tables?

Comment: @Barmar: From the [examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index), it looks like `join`'s `on=` applies to the left side only; they recommend explicitly using `.merge` when trying to join on table columns.

Comment: well we probably wrote our answer at about the same time I guess!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with **merge** function. After confirming that columns are the same types

```
last_use_date.userid.dtype -> object
data.userid.dtype -> object
```

and running this function

```
data.merge(last_use_date, on = 'userid', how = 'left', rsuffix = '_right')
```

I got the same result with NaT values.

I was able to solve the problem by changing the types of keys

```
data = data.astype({"userid": str})
last_use_date = last_use_date.astype({"userid": str})
```

After conversion the merge function was executed correctly.